# Finding AWS KMS ID by alias in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating a AWS::Timestream::Database service and I want to use one of our KMS keys that's been created externally of the CloudFormation template.

I want to use the alias of the key, but I can't find any good way to get the reference of the key into the template.

I've found some references to use !Sub to be able to get the ARN, but how to get ID from there?

Comment: What do you mean by "configured externally "? Also can you show example template demonstrating what you want to do?

Comment: Changed the phrasing to created, as I don't really know which tools been used.

Comment: Its not clear what you mean? Created where? Different stack, account, region? How do you want to use it in your current template which is not shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the following code in my S3 cross account replication CF template for collecting the KMS alias. You can try the same approach.

```
ReplicaKmsKeyID: !Join ['',['arn:aws:kms:', !Ref BucketRegion, ':', !Ref AWS::AccountId, ':alias/aws/s3']]
#ReplicaKmsKeyID: arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111111111111:alias/aws/s3
```

Comment: Thanks, work as expected. I get a validation error, but still works.

Resource template validation failed for
resource BSTimestreamDatabase as the
template has invalid properties. Please
refer to the resource documentation to
fix the template. Properties validation
failed for resource BSTimestreamDatabase with
message: #: extraneous key [KmsKeyID] is
not permitted

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias with your kms id like `arn:<partition>:kms:<region>:<account-id>:alias/<alias-name>`

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:
  DB:
    Type: AWS::Timestream::Database
    Properties:
      DatabaseName: <DB_NAME>
      KmsKeyId: arn:aws:kms:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:alias/<ALIAS>
```